# Storing data for a stage in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to create a VR maze game in unity with a fixed map using 1x1x1 default cubes and a c# script to store the map data. I'm a bit new to this kind of stuff so before moving on I wanted to ask more experienced people what kind of method I should use to store the data for the maze structure. I'm currently looking at a 100x100x100 maze, and my idea was to use 2d arrays with a 'y' or 'n' in each index that determines if that location has a block or not, and if it does, it takes the index as vector values and generates a gameobject at that location. I feel like there are definitely better methods that games like Minecraft use, but I have no idea how they work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft, not all map data is stored. the only thing stored is one *chunk*, which is 16 * 16 * (map height) = 65536 blocks, and the *seed* value, and the blocks that user has modified. Using this seed value, map is generated as needed.

But in your case, it doesn't seem to be that there is some kind of map generation feature. So I think it would be enough to store *tuples*, like `List<(int x, int y, int z)>` If the block that contains wall is more than blank spaces, you can store the coordinates of the wall blocks, like `(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), ...` If the blank space is more, then store the coordinates of blank spaces.

With regard to saving this list, you may consider the way of [JSON Seriallization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to), or if you want to store just a list of tuples, you may construct your own way to store and parse it via `.txt` files.

Hope this answer would help :)